# still having issue with show/hide sub-menu on click

Tags: jquery

My fiddle works perfectly [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VKvPX/10/) But When i save it to my html file it no longer work.

Here you can a see the full file [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/2zJc92pe)

```
<script>
$("#showhide").on('click', function(){
            $(".more").slideToggle();
            return false;
        });

</script>
```

What am i mising?

Answer (score 1):

Warp your code in [**document-ready handler**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) because when the code runs it won't find the *"#showhide"* element in the page: the browser will not have parsed that yet.

*Code*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#showhide").on('click', function(){
         $(".more").slideToggle();
         return false;
    });
});
```

**OR**

Use delegated events using on

```
 $(document).on("click", "#showhide", function () {
      $(".more ").slideToggle();
      return false;
 });
```

**OR**

Put your script before ending body tag.

```
<script>
    $("#showhide").on('click', function () {
        $(".more").slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Also your path to jQuery is not correct. Use

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Satpal, every line of code that I have you can see it on my pastebin Link. i included everything from top to bottom of file

Comment: @wilson382, try with `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`

Comment: yeah there were 2 errors and ready handler and the wrong script source, which approach do you recommend document.ready or putting the script at the of the page before </body>?

Comment: @wilson382, for you currently I would suggest document.ready handler or delegated events. Personally I prefer delegated events

Answer (score 0):

Change the jquery script path to this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

and also wrap the click functionality inside document ready

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#showhide").on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".more").slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```